# Bake Fluid to affect Cloth

Tags: fluid-simulation

I was exporting the fluid as an .abc file and then reimporting it, hoping I could have it collide with my cloth. I know that the cloth would not affect the fluid this way but I thought the fluid could at least affect the cloth.

I tried baking the fluid animation to keyframes but I am failing at that already apparently. The other day I could export it as an .mdd file and I think that I had it keyframed when I reimported it, but I get an error message both  on export and import of mdd.

Maybe .abc/alembic cache is the better way to export that anyways, but, as I said, how can I have it affect my stupid cloth simulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to export your fluid to have it collide. You can save the bake in your desired location, delete every fluid obstacle but the domain, remove the fluid modifier for the domain, then re-apply it. Now here's where the magic happens: set the object to a fluid domain again, and set the bake ***location*** to the same file you used for the simulation. DO NOT RE-BAKE THE FILE OR CHANGE ANY SETTINGS! You should notice that it becomes fluid again. Then add a collision physics simulator to the fluid, and do what you want to it to interact with the cloth. Finally, bake the cloth physics, and it should work.

Comment: I have not tested this, since it is a very old question and I am busy with other things at the moment, but I will accept this answer since it seems you know what you are talking about and did this or something like this already before. Thanks for the answer!